# Calculating mean of several values based on parameters in other columns

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, aggregate

I have a data frame like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(category = c('A','B','C','A','C','B'),
                 value    = c(5.4, 5, 3.4,7.5,6.7,3.5),
                 status   = c('HC','D','D','HC','HC','D'))
```

I want to calculate the mean for the values of all combinations of category and status. For example, one mean for `('A','HC')` and `('B','HC')`. If there is only one value, it should just output that singular value.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation with `dplyr` or `data.table`

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(category,status) %>%
       summarize(mean_value=mean(value))

  category status mean_value
    <fctr> <fctr>      <dbl>
1        A     HC       6.45
2        B      D       4.25
3        C      D       3.40
4        C     HC       6.70
```

See also @PoGibas please repost your `data.table` answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution

```
# defining the set of all combinations of category/statuts in df
all.combinations <- unique(paste(df$category, df$status, sep = ";"))

# creating a function that will return the mean of one given combination
fun1 <- function(x){
  indices <- which(paste(df$category, df$status, sep = ";") == all.combinations[x])
  sigma <- mean(df$value[indices])
  return(sigma)
}

# finally applying our function to all possible combinations
sapply(1:length(all.combinations), fun1)
[1] 6.45 4.25 3.40 6.70
```